# How can I add a library written in CESBO ASTRA to my Android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, lib

I have a module written with CESBO ASTRA. Interaction with the module occurs through the terminal.
I didn't write this module, but I need to add it to my Android application written in Android Studio.
Not every android device allows you to run the module through the terminal, so I want to make it part of the application so that it can be launched by the application.
I have the source code of the module, I need to understand if it is possible to do this.